# Google+ Company pages

Tags: api, google-plus

I am trying to access my company pages in Google+ via its API. However, I can find an endpoint that would return my company page?

I've looked at this endpoint, but I don't see a way of listing all of my companies.

https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the "me", you should be able to use the 21 digit code you'll find in the URL if you look at a page's profile.

You cannot currently determine what pages are owned or managed by a user. You may wish to star [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=115) to indicate your interest in having this implemented.